# Check if user already login unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, authentication

I am making a game on Unity, and I had problem where if one user was login, the second user who login will kick the first one out. I am new to Unity and C# so there wasn't many code I know. I was planning to setup a second Username, but I didn't know the code to check if the first user was logging in the server or not. If anyone could help, I would be really apreciate. Thank you

```
void OnConnection(BaseEvent evt)
    {
        if ((bool)evt.Params["success"])
        {
            Debug.Log("Connection Success");
            sfs.Send(new LoginRequest(Username, "", Zonename));

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Connection Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Each instance of the game should only have 1 logged in user. With hotseat multplayer, only 1 *active* user. That is just common sense of how networking works. The server can have multiple users connected to itself, via multiple clients.

Comment: @Christopher I am using Unity, so I was able to build a second machine using the Build and Run function, is it possible to build up a second player still. Thank you

Comment: A second isntance of the game. It is not nessesary for that one to run on another computer, but it often helps.

Comment: @Christopher I did it. Thank you for your guidance.